# linux pipe data from file descriptor into a fifo

Tags: linux, shell, pipe, system-calls, file-descriptor

Lets say I know that a file descriptor `fd` is open for reading in my process. I would like to pipe data from this `fd` into a `fifo` that is available for reading outside my of process, in a way that avoids calling `poll` or `select` on `fd` and manually reading/forwarding data. Can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean ask the OS to do that behind the scenes on an ongoing basis from now on?  Like an I/O redirection?

No, you can't do that.

You could spawn a thread that does nothing but read the file fd and write the pipe fd, though.  To avoid the overhead of copying memory around in `read(2)` and `write(2)` system calls, you can use `sendfile(out_fd, in_fd, NULL, 4096)` to tell the kernel to copy a page from `in_fd` to `out_fd`.  See [the man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sendfile.2.html).

You might have better results [with `splice(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/splice.2.html), since it's designed for use with files and pipes.  `sendfile(2)` used to require `out_fd` to be a socket.  (Designed for zero-copy sending static data on TCP sockets, e.g. from a web server.)

---

Linux does have [asynchronous I/O](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/aio.7.html), so you can queue up a read or write to happen in the background.  That's not a good choice here, because you can't queue up a copy from one fd to another.  (no async `splice(2)` or `sendfile(2)`).  Even if there was, it would have a specific request size, not a fire-and-forget keep copying-forever.  AFAIK, threads have become the preferred way to do async I/O, rather than the POSIX AIO facilities.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, i guess `splice` in a separate thread is a good choice. `sendfile` has a limit on the number of bytes it can send.

Comment: @iggy: splice and sendfile both have a `size_t` length argument.  IDK if it's better to call them with a small-ish size like 64kiB, or if it's good to use `SIZE_MAX` so your user-space loop only happens if/when the system call is interrupted (by a signal, for example).  Actually transfering 2^64-1 bytes is unlikely to say the least, but you shouldn't assume that the call will never return.

Comment: quoting doc for sendfile `sendfile() will transfer at most 0x7ffff000 (2,147,479,552) bytes, returning the number of bytes actually transferred.  (This is true on both 32-bit and 64-bit systems.)`, but thanks for suggesting splice, that would definitely work

Comment: @iggy: Which doc did you find that in?   It's not in the current man page (Linux man-pages 3.74, sendfile man page last edited 2011-09-14).  So IDK if it's an old limitation that's been removed, or if the documentation was previously incomplete.

Comment: you are right, this is probably not the most up-to date resource http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sendfile.2.html

Comment: @iggy: Look at the bottom.  It is *more* up to date than what Ubuntu ships.  So it's probably still a true fact that just wasn't in the man page before.